# Should I be returning a 301 or 403 to a bad referrer in my .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect, spam, 403-forbidden

Getting several amounts of bad requests from a particular URL such as `site.foo` and I would like to redirect all these requests to a dedicated page.  The `.htaccess` code I've researched and implementing is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://site.foobar 
RewriteRule ^ https://bar.com/notallowed.html? [R=301,L]
```

However, researching HTTP Status codes I'm still unsure with the 301:

```
301 Moved Permanently
This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.
```

or the 403:

```
403 Forbidden
The request was valid, but the server is refusing action. The user might not have the necessary permissions for a resource, or may need an account of some sort.
```

So which is the proper usage case and am I using the proper rewrite rule?  Is there a proper HTTP status code to use to stop bad referrers?

In my research I ran across:

- [Redirect based on referrer domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513850/redirect-based-on-referrer-domain?rq=1)
- [How do you block a referer but for a specific URL using .htaccess?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90542/how-do-you-block-a-referer-but-for-a-specific-url-using-htaccess)
- [Can I block a referring site from my web site](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/how-to/can-i-block-a-referring-site-from-my-web-site)
- [How to block a referrer's full URL and not only the domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284819/how-to-block-a-referrers-full-url-and-not-only-the-domain)
- [How to block referral traffic from multiple referrers and subdomains in .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631518/how-to-block-referral-traffic-from-multiple-referrers-and-subdomains-in-htacces)

In case the next person that runs across this is curious.

Comment: Is this referral spam? Or is this other site genuinely linking to you?

Comment: This is a spam site and I edited the question and added the spam tag.

Comment: Personally I would use a 403. A 301 does not send the right message to me. Plus if Google follows the links, it should also get the message. Cheers!!

Comment: Personally I'd use 301 redirect to ***[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ5LpwO-An4)*** or even ***[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)*** but 403 is more PC correct or even better to block them before they even get to the HTTPd using Fail2ban or similar.

Comment: I concur with returning a 403 as well.  Reserve your 301 redirects for internally migrated url paths (change of addresses).

Comment: Is that a correct way I should write my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the "403 Forbidden" status.  You just need to change your rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://site.foobar 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f

Comment: Rusty on my htaccess.  Do you mind explaining how that is different then my above regarding the rewrite rule?  I think I have my condition correct.  Do you get dinged if redirecting to Google?

Comment: You wouldn't get dinged, but the 403 status is the correct thing to use.   I just changed your rewrite rule to use the `[F]` flag which makes the request forbidden.  I linked to the documentation for that.